# Can the major TV manufacturers’s Internet TV systems access network resource?

Tags: networking, microsoft-powerpoint, tv

I’m looking for large TV's right now for my company to set up in conference rooms. We want the ability to load presentations with out having to have a computer to do so. Our hope is to put things on to network drives and access and display them from there.

I’ve heard that LG’s can do this if you convert the PowerPoint file in to a show format. that’s fine. I just need to get this information to the TV with out the computer attached. Can anyone tell me if companies like LG, Vizio, Sony, Samsung, etc. have TV’s that are capable of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you will want to look for a [DLNA](http://www.dlna.org/home) certified TV.  These will be compatible with a DLNA certified media server and thus be able to pull in pictures, videos, etc.

Comment: That sounds right. and unless some one comes on and lists those companies and their proprietary product and answers for each one (like LG and NetCast, Vizio and VIA) of them. I'm going to say your right.